# PHP WordPress metaboxes not updating

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to modify the Plugin Reviewr to have default criterias in the post review system, instead of having to click on the button "add criteria" to create criterias every time i need to make a review. I need 5 default criterias, that are already available when I get to the review screen.

If I simply remove the

```
<?php if(isset($meta['criteria']) && !empty($meta['criteria'])) :
                    foreach ($meta['criteria'] as $key => $value) {
                ?>
```

and

```
<?php } endif;?>
```

repeating the

tags,but changing the name of the elements, or changing the "key" to numbers for each criteria, I cant get results. In some cases, I cant see the values of each form, after updating the page, or I can see the value of only one field.

Here is the picture of the screen

http://s8.postimg.org/ala0rlscl/screen_ODIDO.jpg

here is the code

```html
<?php

/*
 * Shortcode Display
 * Date: October 18, 2014
 */

class WP_REVIEWR_METABOX{
 // global $settings;
 function __construct(){
  add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array($this, 'create_metabox') );
  add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue') );
  add_action('save_post', array($this, 'savemeta'));
 }
 
 /**
  * Enqueue Scripts and Styles
  *
  * @since 1.0
  */
 function enqueue(){
  wp_enqueue_style( 'reviewr-ui', plugins_url( 'lib/css/jquery-ui.min.css' , dirname(__FILE__) ) , array(), null );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'reviewr-admin', plugins_url( 'lib/css/admin-reviewr.css' , dirname(__FILE__) ) , array(), null );

  wp_register_script(
   'admin-reviewr',
   plugins_url( 'lib/js/jquery.admin-reviewr.js' , dirname(__FILE__) ),
   array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-widget', 'jquery-ui-mouse', 'jquery-ui-slider', 'jquery-ui-sortable' ),
   '',
   true
  );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'reviewr-ui' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'reviewr-admin' );
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-widget');
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-mouse');
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-slider');
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-sortable');
  wp_enqueue_script('admin-reviewr');
  wp_localize_script( 'admin-reviewr', 'vars', array(
    'ajaxurl' =>  admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 
    'title'  => __('Review Criteria', 'wp-reviewr'),
    'score'  => __('Criteria Score', 'wp-reviewr'),
    'delete'  => __('Delete', 'wp-reviewr'),
    'confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to remove this criteria?', 'wp-reviewr'),
   )
  );
 }

 function create_metabox(){
  $general_settings = (array) get_option( 'wpreviewr_general_settings' );
  if(isset($general_settings['post_types']) && !empty($general_settings['post_types'])){
   foreach ($general_settings['post_types'] as $key => $value) {
    add_meta_box('reviewr-metabox', __('Review Options', 'wp-reviewr'), array($this, 'review_metabox'),$value,'normal','high');
   }
  }
 }

 /**
  * Review Information Metabox Content
  *
  * @since 1.0
  */
 function review_metabox($post){
  $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_reviewr_info', true);
  if(!empty($meta)){
   $meta = unserialize($meta);
  }
  // print_r($meta);
 ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="reviewr_nonce" value="<?php _e( wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)) );?>" />
  <table class="form-table">
   <tbody>
    <tr valign="top">
     <th scope="row">
      <label for="reviewr-position-fld"><?php _e('Review Box Position', 'wp-reviewr')?></label>
     </th>
     <td>
      <select name="reviewr[position]" id="reviewr-position-fld">
       <option value="top" <?php if(isset($meta['position']) && $meta['position'] == 'top'){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>><?php _e('Top of the Post', 'wp-reviewr')?></option>
       <option value="bottom" <?php if(isset($meta['position']) && $meta['position'] == 'bottom'){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>><?php _e('Bottom of the Post', 'wp-reviewr')?></option>
       <option value="manual" <?php if(isset($meta['position']) && $meta['position'] == 'manual'){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>><?php _e('Manual via shortcode', 'wp-reviewr')?></option>
      </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th scope="row">
      <label for="reviewr-title-fld"><?php _e('Review Box Title', 'wp-reviewr')?></label>
     </th>
     <td>
      <input type="text" id="reviewr-title-fld" name="reviewr[title]" class="widefat" value="<?php if(isset($meta['title']) && !empty($meta['title'])){ echo $meta['title']; }?>" />
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th scope="row">
      <label for="reviewr-summary-fld"><?php _e('Review Summary', 'wp-reviewr')?></label>
     </th>
     <td>
      <textarea id="reviewr-summary-fld" name="reviewr[summary]" class="widefat" rows="7"><?php if(isset($meta['summary']) && !empty($meta['summary'])){ echo $meta['summary']; }?></textarea>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>

  <h2><?php _e('Review Criteria', 'wp-reviewr')?></h2>
  <div class="reviewr-criteria-container">
   <ul class="reviewr-criteria-lists">
    <?php if(isset($meta['criteria']) && !empty($meta['criteria'])) :
     foreach ($meta['criteria'] as $key => $value) {
    ?>
     <li class="reviewr-criteria-single" id="reviewr-criteria-<?php echo $key;?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="reviewr[criteria][<?php echo $key;?>][id]" value="criteria<?php echo $key;?>" />
      <table class="form-table reviewr-criteria">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <th scope="row">
          <label for="reviewr-title-fld-<?php echo $key;?>"><?php _e('Review Criteria', 'wp-reviewr')?></label>
         </th>
         <td colspan="2">
          <input type="text" id="reviewr-title-fld-<?php echo $key;?>" name="reviewr[criteria][<?php echo $key;?>][title]" class="widefat" value="<?php if(isset($value['title'])){ echo $value['title']; }?>" />
         </td>
         <td class="reviewr-td-last">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <th scope="row">
          <label for="reviewr-score-fld-<?php echo $key;?>"><?php _e('Criteria Score', 'wp-reviewr')?></label>
         </th>
         <td>
          <div class="reviewr-admin-slider" id="reviewr-score-fld-<?php echo $key;?>" data-target="#reviewr-slider-<?php echo $key;?>" data-value="<?php if(isset($value['score'])){ echo intval($value['score']); }?>"></div>
         </td>
         <td class="reviewr-td-small">
          <input type="text" id="reviewr-slider-<?php echo $key;?>" class="reviewr-admin-slider-input" data-target="#reviewr-score-fld-<?php echo $key;?>" name="reviewr[criteria][<?php echo $key;?>][score]" value="<?php if(isset($value['score'])){ echo intval($value['score']) . '%'; }?>" />
         </td>
         <td class="reviewr-td-last">
          <input type="button" class="button button-primary button-large reviewr-criteria-delete" data-target="#reviewr-criteria-<?php echo $key;?>" value="<?php _e('Delete', 'wp-reviewr')?>">
         </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
     </li>
    <?php } endif;?>
   </ul>
   <input type="button" class="button button-primary button-large reviewr-add-criteria" value="<?php _e('Add New Criteria', 'wp-reviewr')?>">
  </div>

 <?php 
 }

 /**
  * Save Review Information
  *
  * @since 1.0
  */
 function savemeta($post_id){
  if(isset( $_POST['reviewr_nonce'] )){
   $reviewr = serialize( $_POST['reviewr'] );
   $reviewr = strip_tags($reviewr);
   update_post_meta($post_id, '_reviewr_info', $reviewr);
   $reviewr = unserialize($reviewr);
   $total = 0;
   $c = 0;
   if(isset($reviewr['criteria']) && !empty($reviewr['criteria'])){
    foreach ($reviewr['criteria'] as $key => $value) {
     $c++;
     $score = intval( $value['score'] );
     if($score > 100){
      $score = 100;
     }else if($score < 0){
      $score = 0;
     }
     $total += $score;
    }

    $percentage = $total/$c;
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_reviewr_percentage', $percentage);
   }
  }
 }
}
$wp_reviewr_metabox = new WP_REVIEWR_METABOX();
?>
```

What I want is : instead of having to click on the button "add criteria" to create criterias every time i need to make a review. I need 5 default criterias, that are already available when I get to the review screen.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is?

Comment: This is what I want : instead of having to click on the button "add criteria" to create criterias every time i need to make a review. I need 5 default criterias, that are already available when I get to the review screen.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need default review criteria to get displayed for add new screen OR edit screen for posts/pages/post_type where criteria is still not applied.
To accomplish this task, you will need to initialize `criteria` member array in the `meta` array value as displayed below:

```
'criteria' => 
    array (size=3)
      '1431405591774' => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => string 'criteria1431405591774' (length=21)
          'title' => string 'Usability' (length=9)
          'score' => string '50%' (length=3)
      '1431405642141' => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => string 'criteria1431405642141' (length=21)
          'title' => string 'Price' (length=5)
          'score' => string '95%' (length=3)
      '1431405648429' => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => string 'criteria1431405648429' (length=21)
          'title' => string 'Features' (length=8)
          'score' => string '75%' (length=3)
```

in php code of `wp-reviewr/core/functions.metabox.php` file, you need to modify array variable as displayed in below code (line no 64 in current version of code):

In the plugin code, random keys are generated using `javascript` but in this it needs to be done by php so `rand` function is used (in js plugin author has used DateTime object)

```
function review_metabox($post){
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_reviewr_info', true);
        if(!empty($meta)){
            $meta = unserialize($meta);
        }
        //this is to make sure when criteria is already saved for post/(post_type), and it is retrieved for edit screen it should not get overwritten.
        if(isset($meta['criteria']) == false || empty($meta['criteria'])) {
            $meta['criteria'] = array();
            $key = floor(rand() * 10000); //create random id
            $meta['criteria'][$key] = array(
                'id' => 'criteria' . $key,
                'title' => 'Category 1', //review title
                'score' => '50%' // you will need default review score also (otherwise it will be 0 and saved as 0%
            );

            $key = floor(rand() * 10000);
            $meta['criteria'][$key] = array(
                'id' => 'criteria' . $key,
                'title' => 'Category 2',
                'score' => '75%'
            );

            $key = floor(rand() * 10000);
            $meta['criteria'][$key] = array(
                'id' => 'criteria' . $key,
                'title' => 'Category 3',
                'score' => '80%'
            );

            $key = floor(rand() * 10000);
            $meta['criteria'][$key] = array(
                'id' => 'criteria' . $key,
                'title' => 'Category 4',
                'score' => '80%'
            );

            $key = floor(rand() * 10000);
            $meta['criteria'][$key] = array(
                'id' => 'criteria' . $key,
                'title' => 'Category 5',
                'score' => '80%'
            );
        }
```

**NOTE:
1. It is required to change the core file of plugin, there is a risk of loosing this customization on any future upgrades.**

PS: it is better to mention which plugin you are using with proper link in question as it took some time for me to figure out that you are actually using https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-reviewr/ as there are many review related plugins in repository.